# Databricks Streaming and Cluster updates?

Tags: databricks

Does anyone know if there's any documentation about how to handle Structured Streaming in Databricks and cluster maintenance updates (runtime, OS, etc)?

I would like to know more about how it works, and if we (user) need to handle that manually or if there's some sort of mechanism that handles that internally.

Answer (score 0):

See [recovery from failures under streaming](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/structured-streaming/production.html#recover-from-query-failures).

For any infrastructure problem that could occur:
 `Hence, to make your queries fault tolerant, you must enable query checkpointing and configure Databricks jobs to restart your queries automatically after a failure.`